# What is the rule of concord/agreement when it comes to using the first noun after 'there is\there are'?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I have come across the following sentence: 'There *were* one or two people I didn't know' in "Oxford Word Skills (Intermediate). I take it that the word 'person' is implied after the word 'one' which makes me come to the conclusion that I should choose *was* instead of *were* here.

I know the rule which goes as follows: the form of the verb in 'there is/there are' depends on the form (singular or plural) of the first noun which comes after the construction, as in There *is* a cat and her kittens in the basket.

Could you explain the choice of the verb in the example from the coursebook and refer me to a reliable source where I could read about this?

Comment: No, "person" is not implied. "One or two" is a coordination of two determinatives forming a single determinative phrase. The verb is the plural "were" because the head of the noun phrase functioning as complement of the verb is the plural "people".

Comment: Could you direct me to any reliable sources to read about it in detail?

Comment: This may help [link](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv128.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the first noun after the verb is "people," so we should chose "were" for agreement. "One or two" is a determinative phrase.

[Here](https://www.educationtopia.net/grammar/numeral-adjectives) is a discussion of numbers as adjectives.

The issue of matching "there is/are" with the following noun is a subtle and [apparently contentious](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not#140888). I think your example highlights this fact, particularly since you have two adjectival numbers modifying a word that takes a different form when singular.

Comment: Isn't the word 'person' implied after the word 'one' and is just omitted?

Comment: @Yukatan I suppose you could think of it that way. I conceptualize "one or two people" as "some number of people between one and two," which makes the verb choice more clear. Perhaps there is a more strict rule that someone could point out.

Comment: "One or two" is a determinative phrase (DP) consisting of a coordination of two determinatives. The DP does not modify the noun, but determines it.

Comment: @BillJ Thanks for the clarification. I've incorporated your info.